# Run code when the rows are between a date range

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements

I want to run a code that transfers data from one sheet to another based on the year (eg 01/01/2018 - 31/1/2018).

The sheet contains 2 columns with dates, start_date and end_date stored as dates, so I did an If statement but it doesn't seem to "understand" the dates values that I stored previously.

```
'Dates columns
Dim fechaIniTarget As Variant
Dim fechaFinTarget As Variant
'Ini = start / Fin = end
Set fechaIniTarget = Range("D2")
Set fechaFinTarget = Range("E2")

If fechaIniTarget.Value = "01/01/2018" And fechaFinTarget.Value = "31/12/2018" Then

   ' function

MsgBox "PROCESO COMPLETO"

End If
```

I tried parsing the dates as integer but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You compare a date `fechaIniTarget.Value` against a string `"01/01/2018"`. Use a real date with the [DateSerial function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dateserial-function) instead to compare date against date.

```
If fechaIniTarget.Value = DateSerial(2018, 1, 1) And fechaFinTarget.Value = DateSerial(2018, 12, 31) Then
```

Also note that you used 2 times `fechaIniTarget` but I guess the second one should be `fechaFinTarget`.

Also don't use `Variant` if not necessary. Instead declare your variables `As Range` here:

```
Dim fechaIniTarget As Range
Dim fechaFinTarget As Range
```

Comment: I'm getting an "argument not optional" error highlighting DateSerial with `As Variant` and `As Range`.

Comment: I just corrected it, the date converts itself to `dd/mm/yyyy` format, manually changing it solved it but now I get `Error 91 Object variable or with block variable not set` setting `Strict On` does not solve it.

Comment: @AbdónAraya There's no `Option Strict` in VBA

Comment: **There's no Option Strict in VBA** ... Who has claimed that?
However, you should use *Option Explicit*

Comment: @JohnyL Yep, my bad, confused the documentation. Got it to "run" but it doesn't pick up any row at all (it skips the entire code).

Comment: ***(it skips the entire code)***
Well, do you use breakpoints and step throught your own code (F8) ?
Read up on VBA debugging before complaining that your OWN code does not work as you want it to. 
http://www.cpearson.com/excel/debuggingvba.aspx

Comment: @peakpeak *Who has claimed that?* What's your problem?

Comment: JohnyL, What is the question?

Comment: @AbdónAraya Try to convert both your cell values `fechaIniTarget.Value` into date `cDate(fechaIniTarget.Value)` to ensure that these are dates and have no additional time part. Please tell us the result of `Debug.Print fechaIniTarget.Value, fechaFinTarget.Value` when your code fails.